# Article multi language selection

Tags: articles, tags, language, multilingual, com-content

I have a multi language site with 4 languages, and I need one article to display in all languages except one.

I need to assign more than one language to each article, how can I override and change the select input to a tag input?

[image]

The idea is to avoid duplicating the articles if I don't have a translation yet, or if there will be no translation needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try using popular extension like Falang.  It will not duplicate any of your article while translating the content.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/falang

Comment: I have Falang, but the one article will appear on all languages, I need one of the languages with more complete articles and different content.
(It's the language where the site is based, must have more complete information)

Comment: My solution was to create one category assigned to that language only, and change the menu on the Falang translation...
This way the other articles won't appear on the main language and vice versa.
But the site translations are a mess, I would like to have a possibility of assigning more than one language to an article.

Comment: If you do not want that article to be appear on specific language you can get the URL and redirect it to wherever you want. That way if user try to go on that article with targeted language, he/she will get redirected to the home page or wherever you redirected it.

Comment: But the article would be displayed on the category blog, then the links would not work.